# Mac Internet Recovery no disks detected to install or to erase with disk utility. Aftermarket SSD is fully functional running Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, internet-recovery

After doing a bit of messing around with Disk Utility I formatted my partition with MacOS installed. I installed Ubuntu just fine and set it to use the entire disk. Everything is working just fine on Ubuntu. I have installed a Crucial P1 SSD to get more storage but before this all happened I was running MacOS normally on the MacBook Air. When I boot holding the option key I see the option EFI Boot which boots into Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu backed up and I don't mind deleting it to reinstall MacOS.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be awesome,
Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of "diskutil list" in Terminal?

Comment: I can't get to the terminal because I can't boot into MacOS.

Comment: The terminal is available in internet recovery... At the top in the Utilities menu.

Comment: Yes I ran that and it lists a bunch of drives but all of them are > 2GB mostly around 1MB. I have 500GB SSD and that is not showing up.

Comment: A few thoughts. Which model is your Mac? If it only supports up to El Cap, were you able to use the disk within el cap? In that case, try reformatting it via gparted. If it's not the latest OS your computer can run, try booting from a newer version of internet recovery or bootable USB drive, as it might just be that there aren't any appropriate drivers to view the disk from within el cap.